# Microsoft PHP SQL Server Connection Issues - How To Troubleshoot What Is Being Blocked

Tags: php, sql-server, connection

I am connecting through Windows Authentication.  I have two webservers on local system.
IIS 6.0 on port 80, Apache 80:80;  I have created a DSN and connected.  I have written simple ASP/VBS Script and connected with this DSN.

I've tried to use this DSN using odbc_connect in PHP and it failed. I then tried the connection as outlined here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296161%28SQL.90%29.aspx

I then created a local dsn using ODBC and verified the code actually works from localhost running on Apache.

My IT guys won't/can't create a user id/password on SQL Server.  The issue is if I bring this up, they play a game of 'what's wrong.'  I can deduce what is wrong ( lack of trusted authentication ); however, I can't rule other issues since I can't look at this server side.

I'm thinking I'm connecting with a DSN, but it's not using the same credentials as my windows account from my web browser.  I attempted to run Fiddler to run this down and I'm not seeing anything jump out there.

I'm sure this is an 'authentication' issue or something be blocked.  I just trying to see if there is something else I've missed or what could be blocked before I go play Twilight zone with the IT dept ( or the nasty old gnomes at the bridge in Dora's world...lol).

Comment: Please add the whole error message (perhaps minus confidential data) you get from `sqlsrv_errors()`.

Answer (score 0):

I have bad news for you: Windows Authentication stinks big time. The exact problem is called '[double hop authentication](http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/archive/2008/08/22/iis-windows-authentication-and-the-double-hop-issue.aspx)' - [google](http://www.google.com/search?name=f&hl=en&q=double-hop+authentication) for it and you'll find lots of people asking for help. Half of them would have solved the problem using something that already failed to work for you - while the other half apparently never solved the issue.

I wrote recently an extranet sensitive data gathering application for a customer that insisted everything being based on Active Directory and Windows Authentication. To cut a long story short, the whole project stopped for a whole month until they gave up and allowed a single SQL Server login for the network connection. Nothing else worked.

Lessons learned:

- don't believe M$ sales brochures where they say it '*just works*' and '*perfectly integrated*'
- a ten minute job of connecting a server to a DB can become a month long showstopper if you disregard the point above
- next customer that comes up with AD and the like can expect to pay dearly for the privilege of forcing me to work with Microsoft's stuff again...